# Are R objects dumped using `dump` readable cross-platform?

Tags: r, format, dump

I am considering replacing some uses of `save`, which exports .Rdata files, with `dump`, which produces text representations of R objects.

Is it safe to assume that files created using `dump` will be readable by R installed on different operating systems (e.g. linux, mac, windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even those from `save()` are readable on all platforms -- I would stick with that format if your goal is *cross-platform* use rather than *cross-application* use (in which case you need a format read by all applications...).

Comment: my goal is to a) support cross-platform use and b) provide human-readable text files; also, I assumed that `save` would be more robust, based on the `?dump`, but how can I be certain that `dump` creates files that are platform-independent (other than asking you, e.g., is it documented?)

Comment: I have asked a separate question requesting a more general reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853050/are-there-features-of-r-that-are-system-dependent. Also, although +1 here, it doesn't specifically answer my question.